# How to compare two array in while condition

Tags: php, arrays

Here is My Code

```
<tr>
    <th width="100"><strong><?php echo $isian2; ?></strong></th>
    <th width="140"><strong><?php echo $isian3; ?></strong></th>
    <td width="10" align="center"><strong>Option</strong></td>
  </tr>

<?php

$pageSql = "SELECT * FROM tcar";
            $pageQry = mysql_query($pageSql, $db) or die ("error paging: ".mysql_error());
            $kolomLain = mysql_fetch_array($pageQry);

 $mySql = "SELECT * FROM tcustomer ";
        $myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $db) or die ("error paging: ".mysql_error());
        $kolomData = mysql_fetch_array($myQry);

    while ($kolomData = mysql_fetch_array($myQry)) {
     <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $kolomData['id']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $kolomData['kd']; ?> </td>
?>

<?php

    if ($kolomData['kd']==$kolomLain['kd']){
    echo "<td class='cc' align='center'> A </td>     
 ";
    }
    else {
    echo "  <td class='cc' align='center'> B </td> 
     ";
  }
?>
```

if code not working, its only compare to first field 'kd' in table tcar.

I'm sorry if it already asking by another but actually i was trying search but still cant get result.

Comment: `$kolomLain` will contain only ONE row of results. the fetch calls only ever return ONE row. Plus, you're fetching from `$myQry`, which is undefined, meaning your `while()` loop will never execute, since the fetch call will have returned boolean false (failure).

Answer (score 2):

change the PHP code segment to

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tcar";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1, $db) or die ("error paging: ".mysql_error());
$kolomLainSize = mysql_num_rows($res1);

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tcustomer ";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2, $db) or die ("error paging: ".mysql_error());
$kolomDataSize = mysql_num_rows($res2);

for($i = 0; $i < min($kolomLainSize, $kolomDataSize); $i++)
{
    $kolomLain = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
    $kolomData = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
    // print your data here
}
if($i == $kolomLainSize)
{
    // no more $kolomLain, but there are still some $kolomData
    while($kolomData = mysql_fetch_array($res2))
    {
        // print your data
    }
}
else
{
    // no more $kolomData, but there are still some $kolomLain
    while($kolomLain = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
    {
        // print your data
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, at 1st print data I put data tkolomdata, and at 2nd print A and 3rd B, actually at 1st, it was double data record out there, and the 'A or B' show up only at last record of 1st data

Answer (score 0):

Try do two while, and put the result of the row in two different value. After compare this.

Comment: yes, two while, or compare the field 'kd' in tcustomer with array of all 'kd' in tcar (field to array) but actually I try the code, and still not finish my problem